# Is it possible to read DBF files into R while keeping the length of character vectors?

Tags: r, dbf

Is it possible to read a DBF file with character variables that keeps the original length of the character vectors, regardless of the number of blank spaces?

For instance, it is possible with a CSV file. Here's an example:

```
a <- 1:5
b <- c("AAAA", "AAA ", "   A", "    ", "A  A")
testData <- data.frame(a, b)
write.csv2(testData, file.path(getwd(), "testData.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
testCSV <- read.csv2(file.path(getwd(), "testData.csv"), as.is = TRUE)
nchar(testCSV$b)
[1] 4 4 4 4 4
```

But it is not with a DBF file:

```
library(foreign)
write.dbf(testData, file.path(getwd(), "testData.dbf"))
testDBF <- read.dbf(file.path(getwd(), "testData.dbf"), as.is = TRUE)
nchar(testDBF$b)
[1]  4  3  1 NA  4
```

In this example the length of each element should always be 4. I've tried going through the source code of this read.dbf function and I've tried using other packages but I haven't had any luck!